# Django form invalid before rendering with a context processor

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a slight issue with my form using Django. On my website I have a 'settings' box on every page (rendered with an 'include') in base.html - each settings box has a form which I am rendering with a 'context processor' however when rendering the form in the template nothing shows. Rendering with `{{global_rebase_form.get_context}}` I get the following message:

```
{'form': <global_rebase_form bound=False, valid=False, fields=()>, 'fields': [], 'hidden_fields': [], 'errors': []}
```

Suggesting it is invalid? My code is as follows

Settings.py

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'apps.home.views.global_rebase_context',
                 ...
            ],
```

context processor:

```
def global_rebase_context(request):
    form = global_rebase_form()
    return {
        'global_rebase_form': form
    }
```

template

```
<form method="POST" name="time" id="rebase-form">
{% csrf_token %}
{{global_rebase_form.as_p}}
</form>
```

form.py

```
class global_rebase_form(forms.Form):
class Meta:
    model = profile
    fields = ['location_rebase', 'time_rebase']
```

Comment: A form that is not bounded is always invalid, since it thus does not contain any data. Hence there is no problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so, if the template acknowledges the presence of the form in the context, and the 'valid=False' is ok, what could cause the fields to not render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that if you would use `form.is_valid()` it will return `False`, this is because the form is not *bounded*. Bounded means that you passed data to it. So a form:

```
global_rebase_form(request.POST, request.FILES)  # bounded
```

is bounded, whereas a form without data:

```
global_rebase_form()  # not bounded and thus not valid
```

is not bounded and therefore not valid. But here you each time construct an *empty* form. It is only if the user submits data, that you will construct a new form object with the data, and then validate it.

Hence this is *not a problem*.